# Rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12)

Tags: ubuntu, windows, rsync

Afternoon all,

I am currently in the process of mounting my windows server 2019 shared drive to my Linux machine which is currently on 18.04. I was able to successfully mount the shared network drive but I am unable to transfer any data via Rsync. The windows server has rsync installed, and SSH. I am able to ssh into the machine from Ubuntu and i can see all the data from the mount.
Below is the error received when i run the follewing command:

`rsync -aznP /system-backups user_1@192.168.1.180:/cronbackups/test`

ERROR:

`'rsync' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

`rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]`

`rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.2]`

I also ran `#sestatus` and it was marked as `disabled`. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear why you are using `rsync` over the network to the Windows machine when you have a shared network drive that you can copy the data to or from.

Comment: Plan is to use rsync to perform automatic backups to the shared drive. I just don't have time in my day to manually back up the files. The only time I can manually back it up is on the weekend and i don't want to come to work on the weekend haha.